# Table with rowspan and hovering

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, mousehover

I have troubles with a table with lot of `td rowspan`. I've constructed it, mixing some ideas from other posts.

On mouse over, I need that the information related to an office be hovered. For example, if I select Paris, his continent, country and other related info should come in red colour.

As you can see in the snippet, it works as expected except for the rows of Germany and Canada:

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").hover(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    $el.parent().addClass("hover");
    var tdIndex = $('tr').index($el.parent());
    if ($el.parent().has('td[rowspan]').length == 0) {
      $el.parent().prevAll('tr:has(td[rowspan]):first')
        .find('td[rowspan]').filter(function() {
          return checkRowSpan(this, tdIndex);
        }).addClass("hover");
    }
  }, function() {
    $el.parent()
      .removeClass("hover")
      .prevAll('tr:has(td[rowspan]):first')
      .find('td[rowspan]')
      .removeClass("hover");
  });
});

function checkRowSpan(element, pIndex) {
  var rowSpan = parseInt($(element).attr('rowspan'));
  var cIndex = $('tr').index($(element).parent());
  return rowSpan >= pIndex + 1 || (cIndex + rowSpan) > pIndex;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">
        North America
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4">
        4
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2">
        USA
      </td>
      <td>
        Ohio
      </td>
      <td>
        Office A
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4">
        Open
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        New York
      </td>
      <td>
        Office A
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">
        Canada
      </td>
      <td>
        Toronto
      </td>
      <td>
        Office A
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Ottawa
      </td>
      <td>
        Office A
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        Europe
      </td>
      <td rowspan="3">
        3
      </td>
      <td>
        France
      </td>
      <td>
        Paris
      </td>
      <td>
        Office A
      </td>
      <td rowspan="3">
        Open
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">
        Germany
      </td>
      <td>
        Berlin
      </td>
      <td>
        Office A
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Munich
      </td>
      <td>
        Office A
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        South America
      </td>
      <td>
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        Argentina
      </td>
      <td>
        Buenos Aires
      </td>
      <td>
        Office A
      </td>
      <td>
        Open
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">
        Asia
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2">
        2
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2">
        China
      </td>
      <td>
        Shanghai
      </td>
      <td>
        Office A
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2">
        Open
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Beijing
      </td>
      <td>
        Office A
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this is happening because in you current code open is only child of first tr only.

Comment: I can manage to remove 'Open' column, but the problem also is with continents.